# Method for returning previous enum value in Java

Tags: java, enums

I've got the following enum:

```
enum Rank{TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN,
          KING, ACE}
```

and i'm looking to create two methods. One that returns the previous value. For example, if the method is called on FOUR, THREE is returned. And another that returns the integer value. For example, TWO returns 2, JACK, QUEEN and KING return 10 and ACE returns 11.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The first problem can be solved by adding method (like `getValue` in my further listing) to the `Rank` enum. It is not the only solution - for example, static factory method can also be used.

For the second problem you should introduce to the `Rank` enum new constructor that accepts `int` value and then use this constructor in enum instances declarations.

Now let's combine these two changes with your original enum:

```
enum Rank {
    TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6), SEVEN(7),
    EIGHT(8), NINE(9), TEN(10), JACK(10), QUEEN(10), KING(10), ACE(11);

    private int value;

    //private constructor which accepts int value for each card.
    //It means that ACE(11) call creates ACE instance which holds value of 11 inside 
    Rank(int i) {
        value = i;
    }

    public int getValue() {
       return value;
    }

    public Rank getPrevRank(){
        return values()[ordinal() > 0 ? ordinal()  - 1 : 0];
    } 
}
```

Now you can just write:

```
System.out.println(Rank.FIVE.getPrevRank());//prints FOUR
System.out.println(Rank.ACE.getValue());//prints 11
System.out.println(Rank.FIVE.getPrevRank().getValue());//prints 4
```

**PS:** for your first problem you can also use this util method without any changes in `Rank` enum itself:

```
public static Rank getPreviousRank(Rank currentRank){
    return Rank.values()[currentRank.ordinal() > 0 ? currentRank.ordinal()  - 1 : 0];
}
```

Example:

```
System.out.println(getPreviousRank(Rank.FIVE)); //prints FOUR
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way of doing the getPrevious method within the enum? This was really  helpful by the way. Thank you!!

Comment: Of course we can do it, my friend. See fixed answer =)

Comment: Static utility methods are not a good solution to anything; they only add complexity to your system and make it more difficult to test. The solution that adds the method to the enum is absolutely fine all by itself.

Comment: you are absolutely right, Dollery. Static utility method is an absolute anti-pattern but can help to deal with some legacy code, which cannot be changed (for example). That's why I added this option in the answer :)